# How to keep 2 objects in html in the same line

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for asking this basic question, call me stupid but i can't thinlof a way to keep these tow 2 objects in the same line as the're in the sam division just take a look at the code,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
.search-input {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.search-input:focus {
    width: 60%;
}
</style>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="reg.php">Join Us</a>
  <a href="abtus.php">About Us</a>
  <a href="srch.php">Search</a>
  <a href="cnt.php">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div>
<div id="main" >
  
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
<!--This object that is to be right aligned-->
   
  <form align="right">

  <input class = "search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Now if you run it you will find that the the search bar and the menu isn't being aligned in the same line inspite each other not blocking the other please help

Comment: You have to put them inline, thats it.

`form, #main{
     display:inline;
};`

Answer (score 1):

If you put a div with flex box (I will call it "container") around both divs, and set css like this:

```
.container { 
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: space-between; 
   align-items: center;
}
```

Your items will be aligned together on any size screen. In this case (when flex direction is row -- not set because it is the default) align-items: center aligns each item vertically (or, along the y axis), and justify content aligns each item horizontally (along the x axis).

Answer (score 0):

You could float your #main element left.

```
#main {
    float: left;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

You'll have to play around with padding for your form as well. If you give it `padding: 15px` it looks pretty good I think. Just give the form a class so you can add a style for it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your menu and your search are in separate elements, if you want them to appear side-by-side it may be easier to place them within the same container :

```
<div id="main" >
  <!-- Your Menu -->
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>
  <!-- Your Search Area -->
  <form align="right">
      <input class = "search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  </form>
</div>
```

Then you can use a bit of CSS so that your search form will "float" on the right-hand side :

```
/* This will make your float stick to the right-hand side */
#main form { float: right; }
/* This will clear any existing floating rules after this element */
#main:after { clear: both; }
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
.search-input {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.search-input:focus {
    width: 60%;
}
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

#main form {
  float: right;  
}

#main:after {
  clear: both;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="reg.php">Join Us</a>
  <a href="abtus.php">About Us</a>
  <a href="srch.php">Search</a>
  <a href="cnt.php">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div>
<div id="main" >
  
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>
  <form align="right">

  <input class = "search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">

  </form>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
<!--This object that is to be right aligned-->
   
  
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

move your `form` to `div#main` and add this to `#main` css

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover,
.offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
.search-input {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.search-input:focus {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="reg.php">Join Us</a>
  <a href="abtus.php">About Us</a>
  <a href="srch.php">Search</a>
  <a href="cnt.php">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="main">
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</span>
    <form align="right">
      <input class="search-input" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
    </form>
  </div>
```